# How to get the exact client browser name and version in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, browser

I'm working on a Spring MVC application, and I need to access client browser name and version.

I have an instance of `HttpServletRequest` in my action as a parameter and use `request.getHeader("User-Agent")` method, but this returned `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko` in Internet explorer 9.

I need to exact number and version. Is there any tools for doing that?

Comment: There is no safe way to do it. The browser name and version comes from the browser (the _client_). It can be easily spoofed, so you can't be 100% sure to have the correct name and version of the browser

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Acknowledging that the user agent is unsafe. Still, in the lack of other ways, you should parse a user-agent header, which in fact is not as easy, as the number of combinations is overwhelming. Unless you want to roll your own, I would suggest

http://www.bitwalker.eu/software/user-agent-utils

source is available at

https://github.com/HaraldWalker/user-agent-utils

the usage is quite straightforward

```
UserAgent userAgent = UserAgent.parseUserAgentString(request.getHeader("User-Agent"));
System.out.println(userAgent.getBrowser().getName() + " " + userAgent.getBrowserVersion());
```

Comment: what license does `user-agent-utils` have? can I use it in an enterprise application?

Comment: The license is available here https://github.com/HaraldWalker/user-agent-utils/blob/master/LICENSE.txt

Comment: You can also take a look at another library, [Browscap](https://github.com/browscap/browscap/wiki/Using-Browscap).

Answer (score 3):

Useful library for parsing the result of `User-Agent` Http Header : [browscap-java](https://github.com/blueconic/browscap-java)